# Как в React перенаправить на новую страницу после отправки формы?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-form

Как в React Router после удачного заполнения формы и нажатия на кнопку отправить, перенаправить на другую страницу?
Формы делаю через redux-form

Answer (score 1):

Сохраните флаг валидации формы в состоянии компонента:

```
this.state = {validate: false}
```

После проверки, что форма заполнена правильно, надо поменять флаг `validate` в состоянии компонента на `true`, вызвав `setState` в функции отправки формы:

```
this.setState(
      prevState => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
        validate: true,
      };
    }
  );
```

В коде визуализации компонента, содержащего роутер, необходимо добавить проверку флага правильности заполнения формы и добавить переход на другую страницу, например, по адресу `/home`:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/form"
  render={() => (
    this.state.validate ? (
      <Redirect to="/home"/>
    ) : (
      <FormPage/>
    )
  )}
/>
```

Если форма не прошла валидацию, то будет отображен компонент с формой `FormPage` по адресу `/form`.

Comment: ответ рабочий, вот только придется импортировать **state** формы компонента в модуль роутера, не так ли? а то здесь, как будто, роутер и компонент формы в одном модуле лежат. разве что только результат валидации (_this.state.validate_) передавать по **store**, чтобы модуль с роутером мог его видеть

Answer (score 0):

- менять url через **location.href = ...** в middleware. как по мне, вполне удобно.
- записывать результат валидации формы в **state** компонента, затем внутри метода **render** можете делать переадресацию, например:

  `render() {
       if (this.state.formIsValid) return <Redirect to="/lala">`;
- записывать результат валидации формы в **store**, и внутри **Router** делать переадресацию (как коллега ниже предложил)
- для извращенности можете даже внутри **componentDidUpdate** или других жизненных циклов сделать переадресацию через **location.href = ...**